# See a visual representation of my Dictionary in SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, dictionary

I'm doing some REST calls in a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow and putting the response in a Dictionary variable.

I've read several [tutorials about the Dictionary structure](https://plumsail.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-work-with-dictionaries-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-workflow/) and kinda understand it, but I'm a very visual person. I would like to be able to see the items in my dictionary. Is there a way to inspect it?

I tried logging it to the workflow history, but nothing comes out.

The tutorials and posts I've found talk about using a chrome extension to examine the REST results, but that isn't telling me what is actually going on in my workflow.

Has anybody else figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way to visualize the dictionary from SharePoint Designer. You'll have to just remember that Dictionary in json form means `{}`
and each line item in the dictionary means another key/value set, or alternatively a key/dictionary set.

```
Person {

   Name: "Mike",
   Gender: "Male",
   Address: {
              StreetNumber: 433,
              StreetName: "Red Street",
              City: "St. Paul",
              State: "Minnesota"
            }
}
```

All are key/value pairs, but Address is a key/dictionary pair. You'd just have to write it out manually on pencil and paper to get a good visualization.

Comment: Unless it isn't working at all like you expect and there seems to be no way to peer into what is going on!